# Force user to click button at least once before posting

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, model-view-controller

I want the user to click a button to add a row on my page before they post the form info.

Basically there is a button on the page which adds a string line to a div, and i want to make sure they've clicked this button at least once. If they have they can successfully post, if not i want to display an error message saying the div must have at least 1 item inside of it

Im not sure how to approach solving this issue. Should i use `jQuery`? Is there a way to do this with `DataAnnotations`

Comment: You should try and implement something first, and give us some code examples if you get stuck, or or question will be closed for being to broad or opinion based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery seems like a good fit for this:

```
/* Lets declare a global boolean variable to hold the status of having at least one item in the div */
var rowAdded = false;

// listen for the add-row click. When clicked, toggle rowAdded.
$('button').click(function() {
    rowAdded = true;
});

// listen for the form submission and check rowAdded before sending the form.
$('#submit').click(function() {
    if(rowAdded){
        // submit the form
    } else {
        // user has not added a string row to the div, prompt them to add a row.

        // prompt method 1, use alert()
        alert('Please add a row before submitting this form.');

        // prompt method 2, print string to the dom
        var promptString = 'Please add a row before submitting this form.';
        $('#prompt-div').append('<p>' + promptString + '</p>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Will users know what to do?

Can you not just add a checkbox that indicates: [] check this to add a row, then a button to submit?

Comment: No, a checkbox cant be used. User has to add a row with a button sadly.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply hide the submit button (or disable it) and show only the button to add that row and when it's clicked show the submit button